# Error "Invalid committer" when trying to raise a gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm not able to raise a gerrit. I'm getting the following error

```
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 1.37 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (6/6)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
remote:
remote: ERROR:  In commit a223c2e038c23ca1a52e6ffa9eb51c4fb8b18f7a
remote: ERROR:  committer email address samurai@gmail.com
remote: ERROR:  does not match your user account.
remote: ERROR:
remote: ERROR:  You have not registered any email addresses.
remote: ERROR:
remote: ERROR:  To register an email address, please visit:
remote: ERROR:  https://gerrit6.labcollab.net/gerrit/#/settings/contact
remote:
remote:
To ssh://samurai@gerrit6.labcollab.net:9418/package

 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> mybranch (invalid committer)
```

I checked in the url mentioned in the error (https://gerrit6.labcollab.net/gerrit/#/settings/contact) the username and email registered is same as from one which I'm trying to raise a gerrit. Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: *he username and email registered is same* Is it `samurai@gmail.com`?

Comment: Yes, both are same @phd